# Adding a Recipient to SendGrid in JSON Returns Body is Invalid

Tags: php, laravel, rest, guzzle, laravel-5.7

**First and Foremost: I am using Laravel 5.7.10, Guzzle 6.3.3, PHP 7.2.9, and SendGrid 3.9.6**

*I only have about 6 months of API experience, so bear with me on the jargan :)*

My client Request code which is failing:

```
 $client->request('POST', 'contactdb/recipients', [
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => [MyAPIKey - Correct and Valid],
    'Content-Type' => "application/json",
  ],
  'json' => json_encode(
    [
      'email' => $emailSent['email']
    ]
  ),
]);
```

Under the SendGrid API Documentation, (Contacts API - Recipients /post) (https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html):

The user should be added as json-encoded 'data' fields. I am trying to avoid sending cURL requests for obnoxious syntax reasons, as well as better error handling. (I have written this in cURL in the past and disliked it.)

However, when I sent a request to this url, which should theoretically add them as a user and assign them a recipient ID, I am having Laravel push this error back to me:

> Client error: `POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response: {"errors":[{"message":"request body is invalid"}]}

I know for a fact that that variable is valid, as I have checked it before this request was sent, so the issue is not the variable as far as I can tell.

Any help would be appreciated - I think that this is a simple syntax error.

I have seen code similar to this

```
$client->setBody(xyz)
```

Is this something I should look at?

**Edit: Thanks to help, I have learned and figured this out.**

Correct and Valid Code that works for me:
(Uri is an extension of the main one in contactdb/recipients)

```
$res = $client->request('POST', 'contactdb/recipients', [
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => My API Key,
  ],
  'json' => [
    [
        'email' => $emailSent['email']
    ]
  ],
]);
```

As mentioned in the comments and answers, by defining the post as json, you don't have to add the content type or encode it at all. Just comma separate with pipes! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to `json_encode` the body yourself, it is done by Guzzle. Just simply pass the array:

```
$client->request('POST', 'contactdb/recipients', [
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => [MyAPIKey - Correct and Valid],
  ],
  'json' => [
      'email' => $emailSent['email']
  ],
]);
```

Comment: Reading into the Guzzle Documentation:

Note

This request option does not support customizing the Content-Type header or any of the options from PHP's json_encode() function. If you need to customize these settings, then you must pass the JSON encoded data into the request yourself using the body request option and you must specify the correct Content-Type header using the headers request option.

This option cannot be used with body, form_params, or multipart.

Should I pass this as an encode and body?

Comment: Simply use the 'json' option like you did initially. Since Guzzle can also automatically set the content-type header when the json option is being used, you can skip that too. (Updated the code from my answer.)

Comment: Thanks. That got me a step closer. Now my issue is that I am getting "Invalid recipient format", but at least I am getting a 201 now :) - Thanks!